# Why access in a for loop is faster than access in a ranged-for in -O0 but not in -O3?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, iterator

I'm learning performance in C++ (and C++11). And I need to performance in Debug and Release mode because I spend time in debugging and in executing.

I'm surprise with this two tests and how much change with the different compiler flags optimizations.

Test iterator 1:

- Optimization 0 (-O0): faster.
- Optimization 3 (-O3): slower.

Test iterator 2:

- Optimization 0 (-O0): slower.
- Optimization 3 (-O3): faster.

P.D.: I use the following clock [code](https://github.com/lemire/Code-used-on-Daniel-Lemire-s-blog/blob/master/2012/06/20/testvector.cpp).

**Test iterator 1:**

```
void test_iterator_1()
{
    int z = 0;
    int nv = 1200000000;
    std::vector<int> v(nv);

    size_t count = v.size();

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        v[i] = 1;
    }
}
```

**Test iterator 2:**

```
void test_iterator_2()
{
    int z = 0;
    int nv = 1200000000;
    std::vector<int> v(nv);

    for (int& i : v) {
        i = 1;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: The problem is still the same, but for ranged-for in -O3 the differences is small. **So for loop 1 is the best**.

**UPDATE 2**: Results:

With -O3:

```
t1: 80 units
t2: 74 units
```

With -O0:

```
t1: 287 units
t2: 538 units
```

**UPDATE 3: The [CODE](http://pastebin.com/N2LHAc24)!**. Compile with: **g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -O0** (and then -O3)

Comment: The two functions are not doing the same thing, so comparisons are meaningless. Replace the `for` statement in the second with `for (int& i : v)` and then run your tests again.

Comment: It can be instructive to look at the resulting assembly language output from the compiler.

Comment: An important thing is that if the compiler sees that the vector has no side effect or used for display, it is allowed to suppress the loop because it does nothing useful.

Comment: @Vincent If this is the real benchmark code the compiler is allowed to do nothing at all. Reasoning about the performance of this is just pointless.

Comment: Please don't fundamentally change the question after it's been answered, post a new question.  By adding that one character, you've invalidated the answer below, which makes this entire post pointless in the context of StackOverflow.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Comment: Mooing Duck: It's only a type error, the problem is the same!

Comment: @ManuelIgnacioLópezQuintero: No, the version without the `&` ought to be infinitely faster in optimized builds, and slower in debug builds.  The version with `&` ought to be identical speeds in either build.

Comment: After the benchmark, add all the values of the vector in a volatile int and display it (to prevent the compiler from erasing the loop).

Comment: @Mooing Duck: it's not! For me it's not! And if you're right, why?

Comment: The version with `&` ought to be identical, the two bits of code do the same things.  However, if the `&` is missing, the compiler can trivially detect that the for loop does nothing and skip the entire for loop.  If unoptimized builds, the ranged-for must make a copy of each number, and then increment the copy, which is more steps, so I'd expect it to be slower than the for-loop.

Comment: @ManuelIgnacioLópezQuintero: Well, now that you've posted the actual timings, it's clear that IN ALL OF YOUR TESTS the loops were removed.  The CPU can't assign `1` to `1200000000` ints in `538` ticks, that's impossible.  Hint: the times should be over ~675000000 in a fully optimized build.

Comment: @MooingDuck A couple things to note:  1) 6ms (or 6 clocks - not sure what unit he is using here) is not a significant different with other things running, and 2) if the compiler noticed the triviality of the loop (highly likely in an optimized build ... possible in an unoptimized build), you are probably correct that it removed the loops entirely - but it is quite possible that it also made use of loop-unrolling, which would allow it to assign the value to multiple elements each iteration.

Comment: @ZacHowland: (A) He's using RDTCS, which is # of CPU operations (roughly). Wait, in the unrelated code here, he was doing averages, so if that's what his output is, one would expect numbers between 1 and 4, but other processes interfering could easily bump that up a random amount...  (B) I did my math assuming it was writing 64 bits at a time, unrolled to 8 times per iteration, which is how I got ~6.7e8.  32bit assignments not-unrolled would be ~3.6e9 operations.

Comment: @ZacHowland: Now that I look at the actual code, the units are nanoseconds assuming he's running on a 100MHz processor >.< It's not convertible to an actual time unit without knowing the _actual_ speed of his processor.  In any case, I'd expect numbers of 7-37, depending on optimizations plus some for interference from other processes or paging or whatnot.

Answer (score 7):

Your first test is actually setting the value of each element in the vector to 1.

Your second test is setting the value of a **copy** of each element in the vector to 1 (the original vector is the same).

When you optimize, the second loop more than likely is removed entirely as it is basically doing nothing.

If you want the second loop to actually set the value:

```
for (int& i : v) // notice the & 
{
    i = 1;
}
```

Once you make that change, your loops are likely to produce assembly code that is almost identical.

As a side note, if you wanted to initialize the entire vector to a single value, the better way to do it is:

```
std::vector<int> v(SIZE, 1);
```

**EDIT**

The assembly is fairly long (100+ lines), so I won't post it all, but a couple things to note:

Version 1 will store a value for `count` and increment `i`, testing for it each time.  Version 2 uses iterators (basically the same as `std::for_each(b.begin(), v.end() ...)`).  So the code for the loop maintenance is very different (it is more setup for version 2, but less work each iteration).

Version 1 (just the meat of the loop)

```
mov eax, DWORD PTR _i$2[ebp]
push    eax
lea ecx, DWORD PTR _v$[ebp]
call    ??A?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@QAEAAHI@Z ; std::vector<int,std::allocator<int> >::operator[]
mov DWORD PTR [eax], 1
```

Version 2 (just the meat of the loop)

```
mov eax, DWORD PTR _i$2[ebp]
mov DWORD PTR [eax], 1
```

When they get optimized, this all changes and (other than the ordering of a few instructions), the output is almost identical.

Version 1 (optimized)

```
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 12                 ; 0000000cH
    push    ecx
    lea ecx, DWORD PTR _v$[ebp]
    mov DWORD PTR _v$[ebp], 0
    mov DWORD PTR _v$[ebp+4], 0
    mov DWORD PTR _v$[ebp+8], 0
    call    ?resize@?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@QAEXI@Z ; std::vector<int,std::allocator<int> >::resize
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR _v$[ebp+4]
    mov edx, DWORD PTR _v$[ebp]
    sub ecx, edx
    sar ecx, 2 ; this is the only differing instruction
    test    ecx, ecx
    je  SHORT $LN3@test_itera
    push    edi
    mov eax, 1
    mov edi, edx
    rep stosd
    pop edi
$LN3@test_itera:
    test    edx, edx
    je  SHORT $LN21@test_itera
    push    edx
    call    DWORD PTR __imp_??3@YAXPAX@Z
    add esp, 4
$LN21@test_itera:
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret 0
```

Version 2 (optimized)

```
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 12                 ; 0000000cH
    push    ecx
    lea ecx, DWORD PTR _v$[ebp]
    mov DWORD PTR _v$[ebp], 0
    mov DWORD PTR _v$[ebp+4], 0
    mov DWORD PTR _v$[ebp+8], 0
    call    ?resize@?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@QAEXI@Z ; std::vector<int,std::allocator<int> >::resize
    mov edx, DWORD PTR _v$[ebp]
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR _v$[ebp+4]
    mov eax, edx
    cmp edx, ecx
    je  SHORT $LN1@test_itera
$LL33@test_itera:
    mov DWORD PTR [eax], 1
    add eax, 4
    cmp eax, ecx
    jne SHORT $LL33@test_itera
$LN1@test_itera:
    test    edx, edx
    je  SHORT $LN47@test_itera
    push    edx
    call    DWORD PTR __imp_??3@YAXPAX@Z
    add esp, 4
$LN47@test_itera:
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret 0
```

Comment: Sorry! You are right! I'll try the new experiments again!

Comment: Zac, the differences is still happening! I'm gonna update the question!

Comment: @ManuelIgnacioLópezQuintero You would have to compare the resulting assembly code for each method.  It *should* be almost identical for these 2 loops, but the compiler may see that it can fix some things because this loop is very trivial.  Also, a single run of it will not give you a good comparison.  You would need to do several runs and compare the results to get a good statistical model.

Comment: @ManuelIgnacioLópezQuintero Also, a difference of 6ms in an optimized build is not a significant difference.  That can be the difference in you ALT-Tabbing to a different window for a second.

Comment: Zac, thanks for your comments and sorry for the & error (the problem is still alive). The results I show have the same values after several executions. In relation to try in assembly code, I don't know how.

Comment: @Manuel `g++ -S -o test1.s test1.cpp; g++ -S -o test2.s test2.cpp; diff test1.s test2.s`

Comment: @remyabel: I'm totally miss with the ASM code. Different lenghts but differents instructions have different cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Do not worry about how much time each operation takes, that falls squarely under the [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) quote by Donald Knuth. Write easy to understand, simple programs, your time while writing the program (and reading it next week to tweak it, or to find out why the &%$# it is giving crazy results) is *much* more valuable than any computer time wasted. Just compare your weekly income to the price of an off-the-shelf machine, and think how much of your time is required to shave off a few minutes of compute time.

Do worry when you have *measurements* showing that the performance isn't adequate. *Then* you must measure where your runtime (or memory, or whatever else resource is critical) is spent, and see how to make that better. The (sadly out of print) book "Writing Efficient Programs" by Jon Bentley (much of it also appears in his "Programming Pearls") is an eye-opener, and a must read for any budding programmer.

Comment: While I agree with the premise of your post, it sounds like he is doing an academic exercise to see how different forms of the same thing compare to each other.  That **is** useful from a learning perspective.

Comment: @ZacHowland, then OP should start by reading (and/or adapting) the benchmarking code for Bentley's ["Programming Pearls"](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls).

Answer (score 0):

Optimization is pattern matching: The compiler has a number of different situations it can recognize and optimize. If you change the code in a way that makes the pattern unrecognizable *to the compiler*, suddenly the effect of your optimization vanishes.

So, what you are witnessing is nothing more or less than that the ranged for loop produces more bloated code without optimization, but that in this form the optimizer is able to recognize a pattern that it cannot recognize for the iterator-free case.

In any case, if you are curious, you should take a look at the produced assembler code (compile with `-S` option).